# Is there a way to use @Asynchronous methods in a @ManagedBean @ViewScoped?

Tags: jakarta-ee, asynchronous, managed-bean, view-scope

I have a ManagedBean Class that will have load method, this load method would then call 2 @Asynchronous methods inside that class.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Loader implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public void load{
      loadMethodOne();
      loadMethodTwo();
   }

   @Asynchronous
   public void loadMethodOne(){
   ...
   }

   @Asynchronous
   public void loadMethodTwo(){
   ...
   }
}
```

This do not work, but calling an EJB class with 2 @Asynchronous methods works well.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Loader implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @EJB
   private AsyncLoader loader;

   public void load{
      loader.loadMethodOne();
      loader.loadMethodTwo();
   }
}
```

Is there a way to make it work inside the ManagedBean class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Asynchronous is not part of JSF and it will not work on beans annotated as @ManagedBean because it's JSF that instantiate those beans.

Comment: Good explanation, I am now refactoring my ManagedBean classes due to the asynchronous changes I need. But I feel very limited using @Asynchronous with this constraint

Comment: As amazing as it sounds, I've seen several times @Asynchronous annotations in JSF Managed Beans and .. wait for it .. work as a charm, do exactly what they should do, delegate business work for another thread and return immediate response to client, client is then free to do other things in Web App.